# Javascript regex to replace only numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a Javascript regex to replace only numbers i.e. all others alphabets and special characters are allowed.

Comment: A simple search can help you to achieve that.

Comment: @Mamun I searched for it and found one but it doesn't entirely accept special characters.

Comment: Then you should include that in the question mentioning in which part you are struggling...

Comment: Actually, that regex was for other languages so couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```js
let string= "26kgsl5"
let newString = string.replace(/[0-9]/g, "");
console.log(newString);
```